# how to iterate a dali metamodel and obtein the property names

Tags: jpa, metamodel, dali

I have this class

```
@Generated(value="Dali", date="2014-07-29T08:43:32.358-0400")
@StaticMetamodel(Country.class)
public class Country_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Country, Long> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Country, String> name;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Country, Boolean> active;
}
```

that I would like to iterate in some way to get the properties and retrieve them in a list

(yes, this one has only three properties, but I do have others with more)

for example

> ```
> public List<String> retriveEntityProperties()
> {
>     List<String> parameters = new LinkedList<String>();
>
>     for(SingularAttribute<Country, String> att : PersonaFisica_.attributes())
>     {
>
>         parameters.add(att.getName());
>     }
>
>
>     return parameters;
> }
> ```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use Java reflection:

```
List<String> attributeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Field field : Country_.class.getFields()) {
    attributeNames.add(field.getName());
}
```